# Добавление в ячейку, если размер числа превышен настройками таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Меня интересует вопрос такой: что добавляется в ячейку, если размер числа превышен настройками таблиц.

```
$sql1="CREATE TABLE  `sanyoka_T1`(`pole` SMALLINT,`pole2` TEXT)";

$sql2="INSERT INTO `sanyoka_T1` (`pole`) VALUES (7657644557557)";
$sql2="INSERT INTO `sanyoka_T1` (`pole`) VALUES (55187)";
$sql2="INSERT INTO `sanyoka_T1` (`pole`) VALUES (87)";
```

У меня добавилось вот такое число 32767. Как оно вычислилось? Здесь вопрос не стоит о смене настроек поля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

само число **32767** является максимальным числом у **int16** (**smallint**), думаю что в твоем случае записывается просто максимальное значение (если превышен потолок сверху) и минимальное (если потолок снизу)

Comment: Отличный ответ.Спасибо